# removing (slice? splice?) item from array based on index

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this,

```
[
    "slug.current == 'current'",
    "parent->slug.current == 'parentSlug'",
    "parent->parent->slug.current == 'parentParentSlug'",
    "parent->parent->parent->slug.current == 'parentParentParentSlug'"
]
```

This is created via this code,

```
path.split('/')
    .filter(i => i)
    .reverse()
    .map((slug, i) => {
      return `${'parent->'.repeat(i)}slug.current == '${slug}'`;
    });
```

I am wanting to remove the "parent->slug.current == 'parentSlug'" from ever being the error I would like to disregard after the split if possible,

I though it would need to something like,

```
path.split('/')
        .filter(i => i)
        .reverse()
        .splice(2, 2)
        .map((slug, i) => {
          return `${'parent->'.repeat(i)}slug.current == '${slug}'`;
        });
```

This returns the below,

```
[
    "slug.current == 'current'",
    "parent->slug.current == 'parentSlug'"
]
```

when what I want is,

```
[
        "slug.current == 'current'",
        "parent->slug.current == 'parentParentSlug'",
        "parent->parent->slug.current == 'parentParentParentSlug'"
    ]
```

Comment: The return value of `splice()` is an array of *all removed items*.

Answer (score 1):

change splice to this

```
.splice(1,1)
```

first argument is the index, second one means how many items after this index should be deleted (including the index it self)